# TikZ in XeLaTeX vs. LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I have a document with some complicated mathematical diagrams (system of commutative maps, arrows and labels).  It seems to build the diagrams correctly only in XeLaTeX.  The rest of the document compiles just fine in LaTeX.  I would like to submit the preprint to the arXiv, which doesn't process XeLaTeX.  I am wondering if there is a quick fix to make the diagrams work in normal LaTeX.  They were created by my coauthor, and I'd rather not rebuild them from scratch.

Following the suggestion of the commenters, here is an example of the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node (d) at (5, 1.5) {$P(\kappa)\star\dot{E(\kappa,j(\kappa))^{R(\alpha,\kappa)}}$};
\node (a) at (0, 0) {$j(R(\alpha,\kappa))$};   
\node (b) at (0, 1.5) {$j(P(\kappa))$};
\node (c) at (5, 0) {$R(\alpha,\kappa)*\dot{E(\kappa,j(\kappa))}$};

\draw[->] (a) to node[swap] {$\scriptstyle\tau_{\alpha}$} (c);
\draw[->] (d) to node {$\scriptstyle\pi_{\alpha\kappa}\times\mathrm{id}$} (c);
\draw[->] (b) to node {$\scriptstyle(\mathrm{id}\times\mathrm{pr}_{\alpha})\circ\pi_{\kappa j(\kappa)}$} (d);
\draw[->] (b) to node[swap] {$\scriptstyle j(\pi_{\alpha\kappa})$} (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

With XeLaTeX:
[image: Here's how it looks with XeLaTeX.]
With LaTeX:
[image: Here's how it looks with LaTeX.]

Addressing another request, here is the full preamble.

```
\documentclass[10pt,dvipdfmx]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{sthm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{llem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{clm}{Claim}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
```

Comment: Sorry but nobody can tell you how to adapt some unknown diagrams. You will have to show an example document that can be used for tests.

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and see your issue. Exactly how are thise diagrams made? My guess: the `xy` package with the `dvips` option. It does not need the `dvips` option anymore.

Comment: Maybe you could externalise the images and then use the frozen images when you upload to arxiv

Comment: Once I fix a couple of missing braces, the figure compiles fine for me with pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX on an up-to-date TeX Live system. We are going to need to see a `.log` file to diagnose your issue.

Comment: @JosephWright Please tell me where I should put braces and I’ll see if it fixes things.

Comment: Please extend the example to a full document so we can verify that you're not using font setups that may not work under pdflatex.

Comment: BTw why code these from stratch, when you can just use `tikz-cd`?

Comment: @daleif No, that wouldn’t be appropriate to post my entire paper here. But are you saying I just change the package to tikz-cd and it’s fine?

Comment: @mbsq You're not being asked to show your full document, but to make the fragment of code you posted into a compilable document by itself. This way people can see if they can replicate your problem and help you solve it.

Comment: @AlanMunn I would think the people here would be expert enough to go based on the info I have provided.

Comment: @daleif Changing the package to tikz-cd did not work.

Comment: Please read: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) and note that we have not asked for the full preamble, but for such a minimal working example.

Comment: You should remove the `dvipdfmx` option. For xelatex it is not necessary and for pdflatex it might cause problems.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you! Solved the problem.  Sorry all for the dumb question.  Feel free to close.

Comment: @mbsq You see, people here need to see the code which reproduces the problem. How should we have guessed that you use this option?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I see, thank you.

Comment: @mbsq, fine that this question is resolved now. For your next question I suggest to follow this procedure/checklist to prepare a suitable MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . It will both improve your question posted, shorten the comment-communication dramatically and make your solution easily available to future readers ;-)

Comment: You of course need to use the simpler syntax `tikz-cd` uses.

Comment: @MS-SPO I litteraly just came to the site to look for that link, thanks

Comment: @daleif, me too, so I bookmarked it : )

Comment: Remove `dvipdfmx`, of course!

Comment: @ Ulrike, @daleif and others posting the first few requests for OP to add a MWE: I really recommend linking the helpful “What is an MWE?” explainer that @ cabohah posted, when you ask for one — it really helps make the process more efficient in cases like this, where the OP is trying to be cooperative but is inexperienced.

Answer (score 10):

You get

```
! LaTeX Error: Backend request inconsistent with engine: using 'pdftex'
(LaTeX)        backend.
```

The help message reads

```
You have requested backend 'dvipdfmx', but this is not suitable for use with
the active engine. LaTeX will use the 'pdftex' backend instead.
```

and now you know that `dvipdfmx` ***must*** be removed (and neither it should be used with XeLaTeX).

Output

[image]

But why not using `tikz-cd` syntax?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=8em,row sep=3em]
j(P(\kappa))
  \arrow[r,"(\mathrm{id}\times\mathrm{pr}_{\alpha})\circ\pi_{\kappa j(\kappa)}"]
  \arrow[d,"j(\pi_{\alpha\kappa})"'] &
P(\kappa)\star\dot{E(\kappa,j(\kappa))^{R(\alpha,\kappa)}}
  \arrow[d,"\pi_{\alpha\kappa}\times\mathrm{id}"] \\
j(R(\alpha,\kappa))
  \arrow[r,"\tau_{\alpha}"'] &
R(\alpha,\kappa)*\dot{E(\kappa,j(\kappa))}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Aside: I don't think your readers will be able to see the dots above those terms; you should rethink the notation.

Comment: +1 I prefer xy package with the tips with sharp points 

Comment: As I said, my coauthor wrote the tikz code, and I don’t want to redo it. Next time.

Comment: @mbsq No problem: you don't need to rewrite the diagram: just removing `dvipdfmx` does the job.

Comment: @Sebastiano try making an injective arrow in xy and compare with `tikz-cd`. At least one reason use `tikz-cd`, also in this example the xy head does not look symmetric, `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ A \ar@{^{(}->}[r] & B }
\par
\noindent
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar[hook]{r} & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
`

Comment: @daleif You're right. I know this difference.